# Unhandled Runtime Error | TypeError: Cannot read properties of null - (reading 'CodeMirror')

Tags: next.js, codemirror

I am using Nextjs 12 everything is fine till today i got this error from Chorme i dont know how to fix it

I am using Nextjs 12 everything is fine till today i got this error from Chorme i dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 3):

I have disabled the chrome extension "Blackbox - Select. Copy. Paste & Search", and it works, there is no more error.

To verify that it works. Try in other  Browser like Mozilla, Safari or Edge to be sure that its ok.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, whenever I press the CNTRL buttons I get "nextjs Unhandled Runtime Error CodeMirror".
Solution is to disable "Blackbox" extension in your browser if you're using it.